# SQL query result issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The query is used to get balance of certain client

```
SELECT  t.[InvoiceID], t.S_Type as Type,
        t.Date, t.Debit, t.Credit, b.Balance
FROM Statement as t CROSS apply
     (SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
      FROM Statement as x
      WHERE (x.date < t.date or
             x.date = t.date 
            ) AND
            x.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID 
            AND x.CustID = t.CustID
     ) b
WHERE t.CustID ='2' and date between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-12'
order by InvoiceID, Type desc, Date
```

out out i get

```
InvoiceID   Type                Date    Debit   Credit  Balance
4          Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  520.00  0.00    520.00
4          Receipt Voucher  2016-01-04  0.00    520.00  0.00
6          Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  160.00  0.00    160.00
6          Receipt Voucher  2016-01-04  0.00    160.00  0.00
9          Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  850.00  0.00    850.00
9          Receipt Voucher  2016-01-04  0.00    850.00  0.00
13         Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  200.00  0.00    200.00
20         Sales Invoice    2015-07-11  1225.00 0.00    1225.00
176        Sales Invoice    2015-12-14  900.00  0.00    900.00
```

the issue is with with sales invoices # 13 20 176 its supposed to sum the debit of invoice and show in balance

so right out put should be like this

```
   InvoiceID    Type                Date    Debit   Credit  Balance
    4          Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  520.00  0.00    520.00
    4          Receipt Voucher  2016-01-04  0.00    520.00  0.00
    6          Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  160.00  0.00    160.00
    6          Receipt Voucher  2016-01-04  0.00    160.00  0.00
    9          Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  850.00  0.00    850.00
    9          Receipt Voucher  2016-01-04  0.00    850.00  0.00
    13         Sales Invoice    2015-06-09  200.00  0.00    200.00
    20         Sales Invoice    2015-07-11  1225.00 0.00    1425.00
    176        Sales Invoice    2015-12-14  900.00  0.00    2325.00
```

Comment: What makes those 3 records special? Why are they summed and no others?

Comment: Your problem is that in your subquery one of you conditions is x.invoiceid = t.invoiceid, so different invoices ID's cant sum nothing beside them selves.

Comment: so what i can do sagi

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic is slightly off in the subquery.

```
SELECT  t.[InvoiceID], t.S_Type as Type,
        t.Date, t.Debit, t.Credit, b.Balance
FROM Statement as t CROSS apply
     (SELECT Balance = SUM(Debit) - SUM(Credit)
      FROM Statement as x
      WHERE x.CustID = t.CustID AND
            (x.date < t.date or
             x.date = t.date AND x.InvoiceID <= t.InvoiceID
            ) 
     ) b
WHERE t.CustID ='2' and
      date between '2015-01-01' and '2016-01-12'
ORDER BY InvoiceID, Type desc, Date;
```

In other words, the prioritization for the cumulative sum should be date first and then when the dates are the same, use the invoice.

This means that all your values are really being miscalculated, because each invoice is starting over (with your original logic).  However, the earlier invoices are fully paid, so you don't see the issue with them.

Note:  in more recent versions of SQL Server, this is much easier (and more efficient) with the cumulative sum syntax:

```
sum(debit - credit) over (partition by custid order by date, invoiceid)
```

Or, if `debit` and `credit` could take on `NULL` values:

```
sum(coalesce(debit, 0) - coalesce(credit, 0)) over (partition by custid order by date, invoiceid)
```

Comment: but now the balance dose not take Receipt Voucher values

Comment: Nothing in this code would treat those differently from debits and credits as in your original query.  This has only re-arranged the boolean expressions in the subquery where clause.

Comment: so  can u help me with another query  that can get me the out put as i mention in question thanks